# Using custom fields in search results breaks pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have been trying to solve this for hours. When I use custom fields in search results my pagination doesn't work correctly. Page 1 shows the posts as it's suppose to, but when I go to page 2 it just repeats the same posts from page 1 and the pages won't go any higher than page 2 even if there's more pages to be displayed. If I remove the custom fields and just query all posts the pagination works correctly. Here's my code

```
<?php $searchm = get_search_query(); ?>

<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$data= new WP_Query(array(

    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(                  
        array(
            'key'     => 'CurrentArea',
            'value'   => $searchm,
            'compare' => '=',
        )           
    ),
));

if($data->have_posts()) :
    while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post();
             get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' ); 

    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a static front page?

Comment: Its from my search results page, if I do example.com/?s= it shows all posts and the page numbers show at the bottom, but if I do a search like example.com/?s=london no page numbers show and I get 404 if j try to go to page 2 manual through url